# how to resolve springboot exception : User Not a managed type due maybe to security configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I developped a spring boot application including spring security facility

here is the main class of the spring boot application

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.demoImmobilierBack", exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class DemoImmobilierBackApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoImmobilierBackApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        return loggingFilter;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

      EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
      return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      factory.setPackagesToScan("com.acme.domain");
      factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
      factory.afterPropertiesSet();

      return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

      JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
      return txManager;
    }
   
//    @Bean
//    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
//      return 
//    }
    
    /**
     * CORS configuration
     */
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:4200"
                )
                .allowedMethods(
                        "GET",
                        "PUT",
                        "POST",
                        "DELETE",
                        "PATCH",
                        "OPTIONS"
                );
    }

}
```

Here is the spring security configuration

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        public static final String CONNECTION_SUCCESSFULL = "Vous êtes connecté avec succès.";
        public static final String BAD_CREDENTIAL = "L'email ou le mot de passe est invalide.";
        public static final String AUTHENTICATION_REJECTED = "L'authentification est rejetée.";
        
        private final MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
        private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    //    private final UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
        
        @Autowired
        public WebSecurityConfig(MyUserDetailsService userService, ObjectMapper objectMapper, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
            this.myUserDetailsService = userService;
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
            this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        }
    
    
    
    
        
        @Bean
        public RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
            RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter
                = new RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter();
            authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(this::loginSuccessHandler);
            authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(this::loginFailureHandler);
            authenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/user/login", "POST"));
            authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            return authenticationFilter;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
            return authProvider;
        }
        
        
        @Bean("authenticationManager")
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
        
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }
    
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http         
            .headers()
             .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
             .and()
               .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/*.scss", "/**/*.js","/**/*.html").permitAll()
                   .antMatchers("/api/produitimmobilier/all").permitAll()
                   .antMatchers("/api/audit/dossier/*").permitAll()
                   .antMatchers("/api/user/createUser").permitAll()
                   .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
    //               .and()
    //           .formLogin()
    //           .loginProcessingUrl("/api/user/login")
               //the URL on which the clients should post the login information
    //           .usernameParameter("email") 
               //the username parameter in the queryString, default is 'username'
    //           .passwordParameter("password")
    //           //the password parameter in the queryString, default is 'password'
    //           .successHandler(this::loginSuccessHandler)
    //           .failureHandler(this::loginFailureHandler)           
    //               .loginPage("/api/user/login")
    //               .defaultSuccessUrl("/").
    //               .failureUrl("/login?error")
    //               .failureUrl("/")
    //               .permitAll()
    //               .and()
    //           .logout()
    //            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    //            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
    //            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                   .and()
                   .addFilterBefore(
                       authenticationFilter(),
                       UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                   .logout()
                   .logoutUrl("/api/user/logout")
                   .logoutSuccessHandler(this::logoutSuccessHandler)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("my-remember-me-cookie")
                   .permitAll()
                   .and()
                .rememberMe()
                 //.key("my-secure-key")
                 .rememberMeCookieName("my-remember-me-cookie")
    //             .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                 .tokenValiditySeconds(1 * 60)
    //             .tokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60)
                 .and()
               .exceptionHandling()
               .and()
               .csrf().disable();
        }
        
        
        private void loginSuccessHandler(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
            String email = (String)request.getAttribute("email");
            UserDTO userDTO = myUserDetailsService.findByEmail(email);
            UserDTO resultUserDTO = new UserDTO();
            SecurityDTO securityDTO = userDTO.getSecurity();
            securityDTO.setAuthenticated(true);
            List<String> messages = (List<String>)(Object)Arrays.asList(WebSecurityConfig.CONNECTION_SUCCESSFULL);
            resultUserDTO.setMessages(messages);
            resultUserDTO.setSecurity(securityDTO);
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
            objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), resultUserDTO);
        }
         
        private void loginFailureHandler(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {
     
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            String message = "";
            if (e instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
                message = WebSecurityConfig.BAD_CREDENTIAL;
    //          objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), "L'email ou le mot de passe est invalide.");
            } else {
                message = WebSecurityConfig.AUTHENTICATION_REJECTED;
    //          objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), "L'authentification est rejetée.");
            }
            List<String> messages = (List<String>)(Object)Arrays.asList(message);
            UserDTO result = new UserDTO();
            result.setMessages(messages);
            objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), result);
        }
         
        private void logoutSuccessHandler(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
     
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
            objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), "Bye!");
        }


Here is the userrepository class

    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    
          @Query("select u from User u where u.email = :username or u.password = :password")
          User findByEmailAndPassword(@Param("username") String email,
                                         @Param("password") String password);
          
          @Query("select u from User u where u.email = :email")
          User findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
          
          @Query("select u from User u where u.email = :email")
          public User findByLogin(String email);
          
          <S extends User> S saveAndFlush(S entity);
          
          void deleteInBatch(Iterable<User> entities);
          
          <S extends User> S save(S entity);
          
          Optional<User>    findById(Long id);
          boolean   existsById(Long id);
          List<User> findAll();
          
          void  deleteAll();
          void  deleteById(Long id);
          void delete(User user);
          
          long count();
          
        }
```

Here is the user repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

      @Query("select u from User u where u.email = :username or u.password = :password")
      User findByEmailAndPassword(@Param("username") String email,
                                     @Param("password") String password);
      
      @Query("select u from User u where u.email = :email")
      User findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
      
      @Query("select u from User u where u.email = :email")
      public User findByLogin(String email);
      
      <S extends User> S saveAndFlush(S entity);
      
      void deleteInBatch(Iterable<User> entities);
      
      <S extends User> S save(S entity);
      
      Optional<User>    findById(Long id);
      boolean   existsById(Long id);
      List<User> findAll();
      
      void  deleteAll();
      void  deleteById(Long id);
      void delete(User user);
      
      long count();
      
    }
```

Here is an extract of the user class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "USER")
@Entity
public class User {
    
    /**
     * the ID of the product.
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    /**
     * male (M) or Female (F).
     */
    @Column(name = "GENDER")
    private String gender;
   
    /**
     * last name.
     */
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;
    
    
    /**
     * first name.
     */
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;   
    /**
     * email.
     */
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
```

Here is the application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=@Marwen1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

here is the tree of the project

[image]

And here is the exception I got

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [/Users/admin/GIT/demoImmobilierBack/target/classes/com/example/demoImmobilierBack/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.

### SHARE CODE

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.demoImmobilierBack", exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model")
public class DemoImmobilierBackApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoImmobilierBackApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the import statements on User class?

Comment: it should be `javax.persistence.Entity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, I replaced

```
factory.setPackagesToScan("com.acme.domain");
```

by

```
factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model");
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception below `Not a managed type` when the entity class is not annotated with @Entity from package `javax.persistence.Entity`. It might be the case that you are importing a different class (possibly org.hibernate.annotations.Entity ?)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in com.example.demoImmobilierBack.repository.UserRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DemoApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ...
    at com.example.demoImmobilierBack.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    ...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
```

I wrote a small app to verify the reason behind the error.

```
package com.example.demoImmobilierBack;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
//import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;//doesn't work

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Dependencies:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>gt</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow-64184381</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I added @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model") but still get the error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User

Comment: I shared it above

Comment: See my updated answer. If that doesn't work. please share the full stacktrace, also the full code.

Answer (score 0):

### NEW IMPLEMENTATION

I did what you told me, but still get the error
the entity annotation is well indeed javax.persistence.Entity;

and I changed the annotation as the following

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoImmobilierBackApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoImmobilierBackApplication.class, args);
    }
```

full stacktrace

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demoImmobilierBack.DemoImmobilierBackApplication.main(DemoImmobilierBackApplication.java:28) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:416) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [/Users/admin/GIT/demoImmobilierBack/target/classes/com/example/demoImmobilierBack/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:105) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demoImmobilierBack.model.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```